# Error copying files with administrator permissions

Tags: swift, macos

Error copying files with permissions of me I have an application that makes file copies to the folder`/usr/local/bin` when pressing a button, but not working I am receiving the following error.

```
Error copying files: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "You don’t have permission to save the file “bin” in the folder “local”." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/usr/local/bin, NSUnderlyingError=0x600002af4900 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13 "Permission denied"}}
```

Although the error mentions that I do not have permission I have, because I wrote a function to get the permissions:

```
func obtainAuthorization() throws -> AuthorizationRef {
        var authorizationRef: AuthorizationRef?
        
        var status = AuthorizationCreate(nil, nil, [], &authorizationRef)
        
        guard status == errAuthorizationSuccess else {
            print("Failed to obtain authorization reference")
            throw obtainAuthorizationError.executionError("Failed to obtain authorization reference")
        }
        
        // Add necessary rights, including system.files.write
        let rights: [String] = ["system.privilege.admin", "system.files.write"]
        var itemsArray: [AuthorizationItem] = rights.map {
            AuthorizationItem(name: $0.withCString { strdup($0) }, valueLength: 0, value: nil, flags: 0)
        }
        
        try itemsArray.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { bufferPointer in
            var authorizationRights = AuthorizationRights(count: UInt32(bufferPointer.count), items: bufferPointer.baseAddress)
            
            // Flags for the request
            let flags: AuthorizationFlags = [.interactionAllowed, .extendRights, .preAuthorize, .skipInternalAuth]
            
            status = AuthorizationCopyRights(authorizationRef!, &authorizationRights, nil, flags, nil)
            
            guard status == errAuthorizationSuccess else {
                print("Failed to obtain authorization rights")
                throw obtainAuthorizationError.executionError("Failed to obtain authorization rights")
            }
        }
        
        return authorizationRef!
    }
```

And the function I am using to copy the files is this:

```
enum CompilerError: Error {
        case userCanceled
        case fileCopyFailed
    }
    
    func copyFiles() throws {
        do {
            let authorizationRef = try obtainAuthorization()
            
        } catch {
            print("Error obtaining authorization: \(error)")
            throw error
        }

        let fileManager = FileManager.default

        let resourcePath = Bundle.main.resourcePath!
        let locBin = resourcePath + "/Tools"

        let destinationPath = "/usr/local/bin"

        do {
            // Creates the destination directory if it does not exist
            if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: destinationPath) {
                try fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: destinationPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
                print("Directory \(destinationPath) successfully created.")
            }

            // Get the list of files in the local directory
            let fileNames = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: locBin)

            // Copy each file individually to the destination directory
            for fileName in fileNames {
                let sourceFile = locBin + "/" + fileName
                let destinationFile = destinationPath + "/" + fileName

                do {
                    try fileManager.copyItem(atPath: sourceFile, toPath: destinationFile)
                    print("Files \(fileName) copied successfully.")
                } catch {
                    print("Error copying files \(fileName): \(error)")
                }
            }

            print("Successful copying of \(locBin) from \(destinationPath)")
        } catch {
            print("Error copying files: \(error)")
            throw error
        }
    }
```

**Please, could anyone tell me where I am wrong?
I already removed the Sandbox app.**

Comment: So creating and throwing away `authorizationRef` at the beginning is going to affect what `fileManager.copyItem` does later?

Comment: @matt Honestly, I have no idea, could you suggest something?

Comment: I'm just asking what your whole AuthorizationRef dance does. Can you explain?

Comment: request authorization privileges to perform operations that require special permissions on the system, but I think this is not good enough since I also copied a large part of the code from research carried out on the internet, I found Apple's documentation to be very confusing for a Swift novice like I. As you are an advanced user, I hope I can count on your help. As you are an advanced Swift programmer, I hope I can count on your help.

Comment: Well, your situation is similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25091011/341994 As in that case, so here too, you are merely obtaining an AuthorizationRef but not using it. You have to embed an executable that you will launch thru Authorization Services, and _it_ will then be able to do the things that require special authorization.

Comment: Is there a way to change the code I posted so that we can switch to using AuthorizationRef?

Comment: @matt, I'm using STPrivilegedTask: https://github.com/sveinbjornt/STPrivilegedTask/blob/master/README.md, it's very simple and not worth the effort of building a Helper Tool, but thanks anyway.